# Trying to find a fanfiction of Harry Potter and the deathly hallows

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

Trying to find a fan fiction of Deathly Hallows where the following happen. It's quite detailed and as long as the book itself.

- Towards the end harry makes a horcrux out of the golden snitch
- Ginny also goes along on the quest to find and destroy all horcruxes
- They go back to the lake to destroy the locket.
- Dudley is revealed to be a wizard whose powers were suppressed in return for Petunia agreeing to keep Harry. After Dumbledore dies he gets his powers back slowly.
- Snape is a bad guy and is in Azkaban at the end.
- The book ends with Ron and Hermione's wedding day
- Harry visits Godric hollow in the beginning alone and is accosted by Pettigrew who is keeping a lookout.
- Ginny is hurt while destroying one of the horcruxes and Harry retrieves the Half Blood Prince book to help revive her.

Answer (score 9):

Could this be "[The Seventh Horcrux](http://www.phoenixsong.net/fanfiction/story/4205/)" by Melindaleo?

The part about Harry making the snitch into a Horcrux is relatively unusual, Snape is indeed in Azkaban and [the epilogue](http://www.phoenixsong.net/fanfiction/story/4317/) ends with Hermione and Ron getting married.