# Looking for a Harry Potter fan fiction set during the time of Deathly Hallows

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I don't remember much from the story but I am hoping someone can help me find it

I downloaded this story few months before the Deathly Hallows book came out, and it was supposedly a leaked copy (it was NOT actually)

In the first chapter there is a scene where Harry (with Hermione or Ron probably) are walking fast in a street trying to get indoors (it was supposed to be the muggle neighbourhood, I think, where Harry lived with his aunt and uncle). I definitely remember them saying that Cornelius Fudge had been murdered and his body was discovered in some street

Somewhere in the middle of the story there is a dinner scene in the Hogwarts dining hall, so I think Harry goes back to Hogwarts in this story

I think it was written in the same style as the real books, with the narrative being from Harry's perspective

This is as much as I remember from the story. Although the writing style was similar to a real Harry Potter book, something seemed off and the story telling wasn't as interesting, and I didn't finish reading it at that time

I would like to read it again if I can find it. it was in a zip file called scarhead.zip, with scarhead.pdf inside. The book itself didn't have a name but each of the chapters did, if I remember correctly. Googling for these file names don't return anything. I think the pdf had more than 100 pages so it was a good length story. It was NOT the [seventh horcrux](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/133482/13716)

Which story was this, and is it still available somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Are you by any chance talking about the book **"End of the Mark"**?

I remember reading this in the belief that this was the actual last book. 
Then I saw the author, **A.P. Towne**, and found he was a college student who wrote the book for a college thesis.

Anyway, I don't remember the plot, but I did remember the author's name which is how I found the story. Unfortunately, there seem to be no pdfs available on the internet that I could find.

Edit: Valorum found the pdf at https://web.archive.org/web/20160331141812/http://www.harrypotterfanclub.com:80/EndoftheMark.pdf

Comment: Ahem; https://web.archive.org/web/20160331141812/http://www.harrypotterfanclub.com:80/EndoftheMark.pdf

Comment: @Valorum that comment should be added to the answer, otherwise the answer should be moved to a comment.

Comment: And this is not it sadly

Comment: thanks @Valorum! @user13267 And I'm sorry this isn't the book you wanted